# Set the number of digits when labeling a file in Python

Tags: python

When I want to save a file and I use, for example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
t=0.1
fig.savefig("filename%f.png" % t)
```

the name of the file will be "filename0.100000.png"
How can I control the number of digits, and decide for example to save the file as "filename0.10.png" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest change to the code above would be to add a precision specifier between the `%` and the `f`, e.g. `%.2f`:

```
In [1]: "filename%.2f.png" % 0.1
Out[1]: 'filename0.10.png'
```

Such format specifiers are described in the [library documentation for the string types](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), but as the note at the top of that section mentions it would be worth investigating newer and more flexible options such as [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and the [`format` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 1):

Treat t as a string, it would be simpler.

```
fig.savefig("filename{}.png".format(getID(9))
```